# How to plugin Groovy editor and compiler offline in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin

I am using company proxy and not able to plugin from marketplace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the github page, on the right are releases. If you select the release that you want, at the very bottom of that release's page is a list of zipped updatesites, where you can download it from, ex. https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/4.0.0-Release-Notes You can then unzip it and install it manually.

Additionally, if you want Eclipse to work through your proxy, add the following in your eclipse.ini file:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
-Dhttp.proxyHost=your_proxyservername.your.org
-Dhttp.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
-Dhttp.proxyUser=your_username
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=your_password
-Dhttps.proxyHost=your_proxyservername.your.org
-Dhttps.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
-Dhttps.proxyUser=your_username
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=your_password
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf.retry=5
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.connectTimeout=15000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=1000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.retryAttempts=20
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=1000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.connectTimeout=3000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.readTimeout=1000
```

Comment: No need to unzip. Eclipse can handle an update site archive from the install dialog.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'm using Luna, so maybe it was introduced later. Maybe it was always there and I didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: Help > Install New Software... > Add... > Archive...  (confirmed as far back as Indigo (3.7))